# having trouble in installation of kivy package, exit code: 1

Tags: python, kivy

pip install kivy
Collecting kivy
Using cached Kivy-2.1.0.tar.gz (23.8 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [10 lines of output]
Collecting setuptools
Using cached setuptools-67.6.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
Collecting wheel
Using cached wheel-0.40.0-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
Collecting cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.28,>=0.24
Using cached Cython-0.29.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (983 kB)
Collecting kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.3
Using cached kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev-0.3.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (3.9 MB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5 (from versions: 0.5.1, 0.6.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

i basically try to install kivy but it failed, this had happend with my other packages and modules also.

Comment: It would be easier to read and tell if your missing something if you just copy and pasted the whole error message without removing parts and kept the formatting the same as pip's output.

Answer (score 1):

Kivy won't work in Python 3.11.x versions.
I would say use Python 3.9.6
Use the command in cmd : pip install kivy[full]